# Parse Json and insert into oracle table

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have a json variable and I want to insert all data to my table.

The json response is like this:

```
    {
    "data": [{
        "pid": "10",
        "name": "sss",
        "consumer_price": "100",
        "discount": "10",
        "sale_price": "90"
    }, {
        "pid": "11",
        "name": "fff",
        "consumer_price": "100",
        "discount": "10",
        "sale_price": "90"
    }]
 }
```

I try using JSON_TABLE to insert the values into my table

```
INSERT INTO tbl_product_temp (pid, name, consumer_price,discount,sale_price)

    SELECT key1, key2 , key3,key4,key5
      FROM JSON_TABLE (' 

       {
    "data": [{
        "pid": "10",
        "name": "sss",
        "consumer_price": "100",
        "discount": "10",
        "sale_price": "90"
    }, {
        "pid": "11",
        "name": "fff",
        "consumer_price": "100",
        "discount": "10",
        "sale_price": "90"
    }]

 }
',
                       '$.data'
                       COLUMNS 
                       key1 VARCHAR2 PATH '$.pid',
                       key2 VARCHAR2 PATH '$.name',
                       key3 VARCHAR2 PATH '$.consumer_price',
                       key4 VARCHAR2 PATH '$.discount',
                       key5 VARCHAR2 PATH '$.sale_price'
                       );
```

but it does not work. actually it works for one set of data but for more it still does not work
please help me.

Comment: "but it does not work" tells exactly nothing to us. What the error you get?

Comment: @astentx: hi, it does not have any error. the query return nothings. I made a little mistake and someone find the problem, thank you anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.data` selects the array, but the array doesn't have a `.pid` key, for example. `$.data[*]` selects all the items in the array, which is what you want.

```
SELECT key1, key2 , key3,key4,key5
      FROM JSON_TABLE (' 

       {
    "data": [{
        "pid": "10",
        "name": "sss",
        "consumer_price": "100",
        "discount": "10",
        "sale_price": "90"
    }, {
        "pid": "11",
        "name": "fff",
        "consumer_price": "100",
        "discount": "10",
        "sale_price": "90"
    }]

 }
',
                       '$.data[*]'
                       COLUMNS 
                       key1 VARCHAR2 PATH '$.pid',
                       key2 VARCHAR2 PATH '$.name',
                       key3 VARCHAR2 PATH '$.consumer_price',
                       key4 VARCHAR2 PATH '$.discount',
                       key5 VARCHAR2 PATH '$.sale_price'
                       );
```

Comment: Thanks You save me. I merge your solution with this:`https://stackoverflow.com/a/64717873/12780274` And work for me.

Comment: this tutorial is for big json in python `https://stackoverflow.com/a/73168799/12780274`