# How do I Update Oracle database by JSON data with 1 query?

Tags: oracle, sql-update, oracle19c

I am trying to Update below sample `json` data into an Oracle version 19 table. (I want update 1000 rows from `json` with 1 query):

```
create table jt_test (
  CUST_NUM int, SORT_ORDER int, CATEGORY varchar2(100)
);
       
   [
            {"CUST_NUM": 12345, "SORT_ORDER": 1, "CATEGORY": "ICE CREAM"}
            {"CUST_NUM": 12345, "SORT_ORDER": 2, "CATEGORY": "ICE CREAM"}
            {"CUST_NUM": 12345, "SORT_ORDER": 3, "CATEGORY": "ICE CREAM"}
           ]
```

I use this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64717873/12780274)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73168799/12780274) for insert rows from `json` and that work perfect. But for update rows I have no idea. How can I do?
Note: I use Oracle19C and connect and insert to db with cx_Oracle module python.

Code for Inserting by json to Oracle columns:

```
DECLARE 
  myJSON  varchar2(1000) := '[
  {"CUST_NUM": 12345, "SORT_ORDER": 1, "CATEGORY": "ICE CREAM"},
  {"CUST_NUM": 12345, "SORT_ORDER": 2, "CATEGORY": "ICE CREAM"},
  {"CUST_NUM": 12345, "SORT_ORDER": 3, "CATEGORY": "ICE CREAM"}
]';

BEGIN
  insert into jt_test
    select * from json_table ( myjson, '$[*]'
      columns ( 
        CUST_NUM, SORT_ORDER, CATEGORY
      )
    );
END;
```

Comment: Use [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F) statement with JSON table as a source to insert/update rows in a table. But you also can convert this JSON into  dict at the Python side and use `executemany` with [bind variables](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-by-name-or-position) to insert this data via plain `insert ... values (...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Developer use below code :

```
MERGE INTO jt_test destttt  using(  
SELECT  CUST_NUM,SORT_ORDER,CATEGORY FROM json_table  (
'[
  {"CUST_NUM": 12345, "SORT_ORDER": 1, "CATEGORY": "ICE CREAM"},
  {"CUST_NUM": 12345, "SORT_ORDER": 2, "CATEGORY": "ICE CREAM"},
  {"CUST_NUM": 12345, "SORT_ORDER": 3, "CATEGORY": "ICE CREAM"}
]'
,'$[*]'
       COLUMNS  
      CUST_NUM int PATH '$.CUST_NUM ',
      SORT_ORDER int PATH '$.SORT_ORDER ',
     CATEGORY varchar2  PATH '$.CATEGORY ' ) )  srccccc


  ON ( destttt.CUST_NUM= srccccc.CUST_NUM)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET destttt.CATEGORY=srccccc.CATEGORY

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( CUST_NUM,SORT_ORDER,CATEGORY) VALUES (srccccc.CUST_NUM,srccccc.SORT_ORDER,srccccc.CATEGORY);
```

---

In python with [`cx_Oracle`](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle) use below code :

```
 long_json_string = '''[
    {"CUST_NUM": 12345, "SORT_ORDER": 1, "CATEGORY": "ICE CREAM"},
    {"CUST_NUM": 12345, "SORT_ORDER": 2, "CATEGORY": "ICE CREAM"},
    {"CUST_NUM": 12345, "SORT_ORDER": 3, "CATEGORY": "ICE CREAM"}
  ]'''

sql = '''
    DECLARE      jsonvalue  CLOB :=  :long_json_string     ;  
    begin  
     MERGE INTO jt_test destttt  using(  
        SELECT  CUST_NUM,SORT_ORDER,CATEGORY FROM json_table  (jsonvalue
         
        ,'$[*]'
               COLUMNS  
              CUST_NUM int PATH '$.CUST_NUM',
              SORT_ORDER int PATH '$.SORT_ORDER',
             CATEGORY varchar2  PATH '$.CATEGORY' ) )  srccccc
        
        
          ON ( destttt.CUST_NUM= srccccc.CUST_NUM)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET destttt.CATEGORY=srccccc.CATEGORY
        
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( CUST_NUM,SORT_ORDER,CATEGORY) VALUES (srccccc.CUST_NUM,srccccc.SORT_ORDER,srccccc.CATEGORY);
                '''
cursor.execute(sql, long_json_string=long_json_string)
```

Note1: Do not forget in end use `commit`.

Note 2: Make sure that the column you use as a comparison is not repeated in a json and causes deadlock.

Note 3: there is case sensitivity json keys, that is, `CUST_NUM` is different from `cust_num` and `CUST_num` and ...

Wrong :  `CUST_NUM int PATH '$.CUST_num' or   CUST_NUM int PATH '$.cusr _num'`

Ok:  `CUST_NUM int PATH '$.CUST_NUM'`